# accessing d3js visualizations offline

Tags: d3.js, plunker

All,

A quick apologetic preamble: I am very new to coding, html, d3.js, etc.

I have been creating visualizations of a network of firms using the Plunker website. One is very similar to Mike Bostock's Hierarchical Edge Bundling diagram: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999. I have an index.html file which is virtually the same as his, but my .json file has different data. Those are the only 2 files in my "plunk".

I want to present this visualization at a conference but am unsure how to do so without logging into Plunker during the session, and what if the internet connection is not good?...

Is there a way to access these visualizations offline? Can I somehow save them to a thumb drive and load them when needed? Maybe import them into a Latex Beamer presentation? If this has been discussed or is trivial, please point me in the right direction.

One note: I have tried right-clicking on the image in Plunker and doing a "save-as", but while the resulting html file does look like my image, it does not have the same interactive features that I need (the highlighting of the links that occurs during mouseover).

Thanks for any and all help.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

When I was testing a d3 visualisation, I was just opening the plain html file with the js in chrome, the data was included as a variable within the file as browsers won't load data from files on your computer (security issues)...

I was however loading the d3 scripts from an external source, which chrome doesn't mind.

You could possibly include the d3 scripts within an html file. Then you shouldn't need to be online. But I've never tested this, so make sure you can do it offline before the presentation.

Edit:

```
var locations =
[
{"name": "Cochlear", "id": 1},
{"name": "DCN", "id": 2},
{"name": "AVCN", "id": 3},
{"name": "PVCN", "id": 4}
];
var locCircles = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "locations")
.selectAll("circle")
.data(locations)
.enter()
.append('circle')
.attr('cx', function(d) { return xPoint(d.id) })//centre locations around xPoints
.attr('cy', height/2)
.attr('r', 55)
.attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.id) });
```

This created circles in a d3 force-style graph.

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks so much for your reply. Could you say more about how the "data was included as a variable within the file"? I have a .json file with all of my data in it, and am unsure how to just put it into the html file. a ham-fisted copy-paste didn't work...

Comment: the code currently is: d3.json("alldropped_may24.json", funct[code goes on]. I've tried including a filepath (using both forwards and back slashes), copying the json data and pasting between the quotes, etc.

Comment: Alternatively, can I use something other than a browser to view the html output? If they are built with these security concerns, I don't mind looking at the visualization using some other program. Maybe an IDE? Thanks again!

Comment: I had 3 variables as JSON arrays, var locations = [...JSON]; etc, then instead of using d3.json(function...) I just used d3 functions with the data variables: var locations = svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "locations")
 .selectAll("circle")
 .data(locations)...; sorry that's a bit messy. I haven't used an IDE, I tried one, but found it a bit slow.

Comment: Thank you, Oliver. This is very helpful!

Comment: No worries, hope you get it sorted.